# Save file without first and last double quotes

Tags: python, json

I am trying to save my data to a file. My problem is the file i saved contains double quotes at the first and the last of a line. I have tried many ways to solve it from str.replace(), strip, csv to json, pickle. However, the problem has been still persistent. I have got stuck with it. Please help me. I will detail my problem below.

Firstly, I have a file called angles.txt like that:

```
{'left_w0': -2.6978887076110842, 'left_w1': -1.3257428944152834, 'left_w2':     -1.7533400385498048, 'left_e0': 0.03566505327758789, 'left_e1': 0.6948932961    181641, 'left_s0': -1.1665923878540039, 'left_s1': -0.6726505747192383}     
{'left_w0': -2.6967382220214846, 'left_w1': -0.8440729275695802, 'left_w2':     -1.7541070289428713, 'left_e0': 0.036048548474121096, 'left_e1': 0.166820410    49194338, 'left_s0': -0.7731263162109375, 'left_s1': -0.7056311616210938}
```

I read line by line from the text file and transfer to a dict variable called data. Here is the reading file code:

```
def read_data_from_file(file_name):
    data = dict()
    f = open(file_name, 'r')
    for index_line in range(1, number_lines +1):
      data[index_line] = eval(f.readline())
    f.close()
    return data
```

Then I changed something in the data. Something like data[index_line]['left_w0'] = data[index_line]['left_w0'] + 0.0006. After that I wrote my data into another text file. Here is the code:

```
def write_data_to_file(data, file_name)
    f = open(file_name, 'wb')
    data_convert = dict()
    for index_line in range(1, number_lines):
       data_convert[index_line] = repr(data[index_line])
       data_convert[index_line] = data_convert[index_line].replace('"','') #  I also used strip
       json.dump(data_convert[index_line], f)
       f.write('\n')
    f.close()
```

The result I received in the new file is:

```
"{'left_w0': -2.6978887076110842, 'left_w1': -1.3257428944152834, 'left_w2':     -1.7533400385498048, 'left_e0': 0.03566505327758789, 'left_e1': 0.6948932961    181641, 'left_s0': -1.1665923878540039, 'left_s1': -0.6726505747192383}"    
"{'left_w0': -2.6967382220214846, 'left_w1': -0.8440729275695802, 'left_w2':     -1.7541070289428713, 'left_e0': 0.036048548474121096, 'left_e1': 0.166820410    49194338, 'left_s0': -0.7731263162109375, 'left_s1': -0.7056311616210938}"
```

I cannot remove "".

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify your code by removing unnecessary transformations:

```
import json

def write_data_to_file(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(data, file)

def read_data_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        return json.load(file)
```